# How to create multiple rows from a data frame's column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm having a Python Data Frame

Here we are having 2 column SKU1 and SKU2

[image: Here we are having 2 column SKU1 and SKU2]

But I need to convert both the column in one column Like in this picture:
[image: In this picture you can see order number 103 is written doubled and both SKU converted into one column]

In this picture you can see order number 103 is written doubled and both SKU converted into one column

Answer (score 0):

```py
pd.concat([
    df[['OrderId','ProductName','SKU1']].rename({'SKU1':'SKU'},axis=1),  df[['OrderId','ProductName','SKU2']].rename({'SKU2':'SKU'},axis=1).dropna()
])
```